# How to use type parameter in typealias?

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias

I want to use a typealias for a function which is used in a generic class. One of the parameters of the function uses a generic type of the class. This is a simplified example:

```
class Bar {}

// no typealias - works
class TestGeneric<T: Bar> {
    let myFunc: (T) -> String

    init(myFunc: (T) -> String) {
        self.myFunc = myFunc
    }
}

let myFunc: (Bar) -> String = {(bar: Bar) in
    return "hello"
}

let test = TestGeneric<Bar>(myFunc: myFunc)
println(test.myFunc(Bar()))

// typealias - doesn't compile
class TestTypealias<T: Bar> {
    typealias MyFuncGeneric = (T) -> String

    let myFunc: MyFuncGeneric

    init(myFunc: MyFuncGeneric) {
        self.myFunc = myFunc
    }
}

let myFunc2: TestTypealias.MyFuncGeneric = {(bar: Bar) in
    return "hello"
}

let test2 = TestTypealias<Bar>(myFunc: myFunc2) // Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TestTypealias<Bar>' with an argument list of type '(myFunc: T -> String)'
println(test2.myFunc(Bar()))
```

Is there a way to solve this? Or do I have to forgo typealias when using generics? In the actual code I have a lot of parameters and really need a typealias...

(Swift 1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing

```
class TestGeneric<T: Bar>
```

all you've really done is to define T universally as being of type Bar when used inside of a method, so you can write this:

```
func myFunc(aValue:T) {

}
```

instead of this:

```
func myFunc<T: Bar>(aValue:T) {

    }
```

each time you want to define T as being of type Bar.

If you want the class itself to be generic you use only `<T>`, for example: `class TestGeneric<T>` and type is defined upon initializing.

```
class Bar {}

// no typealias - works
class TestGeneric<T> {
    let myFunc: (T) -> String

    init(myFunc: (T) -> String) {
        self.myFunc = myFunc
    }
}

let myFunc: Bar -> String = {(bar: Bar) in
    return "hello"
}

let test = TestGeneric<Bar>(myFunc: myFunc)
println(test.myFunc(Bar()))

// typealias - doesn't compile
class TestTypealias<T> {
    typealias MyFuncGeneric = T -> String
    func myFunc(aValue:T) {

    }
    let myFunc: MyFuncGeneric

    init(myFunc: MyFuncGeneric) {

        self.myFunc = myFunc
    }
}

let myFunc2: TestTypealias<Bar>.MyFuncGeneric = {(bar: Bar) in
    return "hello"
}

let test2 = TestTypealias<Bar>(myFunc: myFunc2)   
println(test2.myFunc(Bar()))
```

Comment: I need the class to be generic and constrain the type to be of class Bar (isA), which is why I use `<T: Bar>`. What I was missing was this little thing: to declare the function as type `TestTypealias<Bar>.MyFuncGeneric` instead of `TestTypealias.MyFuncGeneric`. This also explains why my simplified version of Gregzo's code works, he just didn't specify the type and the compiler inferes it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This compiles and behaves as expected:

```
class Test< T >
{
    typealias GenFunc = ( thing: T ) -> Void

    let thing : T

    init( thing: T )
    {
        self.thing = thing
    }

    func ExecuteFunc( genFunc: GenFunc )
    {
        genFunc( thing: self.thing )
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let t = Test( thing: "blah" )

t.ExecuteFunc()
{ ( thing: String ) -> Void in
    println( thing )
}
```

Comment: I reduced your example to the smallest difference to mine and found out, that what causes the compiler error is the type declaration of the function! so if I write `let myFunc2 = {(bar: Bar) in
        return "hello"
    }` instead of `let myFunc2: TestTypealias.MyFuncGeneric = {(bar: Bar) in
        return "hello"
    }` it compiles...